# Create quarter: month dictionary in Python from varied arrays of quarters and months

Tags: python

**Basic Problem**
Given a list of quarters and a list of months:

```
quarters = ['Q1-21', 'Q2-21', 'Q3-21', 'Q4-21', 'Q1-22', 'Q2-22', 'Q3-22', 'Q4-22']  

months = 
['JAN-21', 'FEB-21', 'MAR-21',   'APR-21', 'MAY-21', 'JUN-21', 
'JUL-21','AUG-21', 'SEP-21','OCT-21', 'NOV-21', 'DEC-21', 
'JAN-22', 'FEB-22','MAR-22', 'APR-22', 'MAY-22', 'JUN-22', 
'JUL-22', 'AUG-22', 'SEP-22','OCT-22', 'NOV-22', 'DEC-22']
```

I want to create a dictionary that lists component months indexed by quarter.
This is simple to achieve by splitting the month array into the appropriate number of sub arrays and then zipping together:

```
dict(zip(quarters,np.split(months, 8)))

{'Q1-21': ['JAN-21', 'FEB-21', 'MAR-21'],
 'Q2-21': ['APR-21', 'MAY-21', 'JUN-21'],
 'Q3-21': ['JUL-21', 'AUG-21', 'SEP-21'],
 'Q4-21': ['OCT-21', 'NOV-21', 'DEC-21'],
 'Q1-22': ['JAN-22', 'FEB-22', 'MAR-22'],
 'Q2-22': ['APR-22', 'MAY-22', 'JUN-22'],
 'Q3-22': ['JUL-22', 'AUG-22', 'SEP-22'],
 'Q4-22': ['OCT-22', 'NOV-22', 'DEC-22']}
```

**Extended Problem**
This is no problem if the quarters and months lists are complete and correctly ordered (as above), but I need to be able to  accommodate situations in which elements are missing. i.e.:

```
quarters = ['Q2-21', 'Q3-21', 'Q4-21', 'Q1-22', 'Q2-22', 'Q3-22']  
months = 
['MAY-21', 'JUN-21', 
'JUL-21','AUG-21', 'SEP-21',
'OCT-21', 'NOV-21', 
'JAN-22', 'FEB-22','MAR-22', 
'APR-22', 'MAY-22', 'JUN-22', 
'JUL-22', 'AUG-22', 'SEP-22',
'OCT-22']
```

In this instance the desired output would be:

```
{'Q2-21': ['MAY-21', 'JUN-21'],
 'Q3-21': ['JUL-21', 'AUG-21', 'SEP-21'],
 'Q4-21': ['OCT-21', 'NOV-21'],
 'Q1-22': ['JAN-22', 'FEB-22', 'MAR-22'],
 'Q2-22': ['APR-22', 'MAY-22', 'JUN-22'],
 'Q3-22': ['JUL-22', 'AUG-22', 'SEP-22'],
 'Q4-22': ['OCT-22']}
```

**Initial Solution**
Using datetimes and offsets, I have been able to achieve this by creating an appropriately formatted list of months from each listed quarter that is present in the month list and then using dictionary comprehension to associate with the relevant quarter key:

```
month_vals = [
    [
        #create appropriate month string
        calendar.month_name[m.month][:3].upper() + q[-3:]  
        
        #list all months in quarter
        for m in pd.date_range(pd.to_datetime(q[-2:] + q[:2]), 
                               pd.to_datetime(q[-2:] + q[:2]) + pd.offsets.QuarterEnd(),
                               freq='MS')
        
        #check membership in month list
        if calendar.month_name[m.month][:3].upper() + q[-3:] in months] for q in quarters
    ]

#create dictionary
{k:v for k,v in zip(quarters, month_vals)}
```

My solution does not feel very efficient and I wondered if there was a more elegant method to achieve the output?

Comment: This is a question more appropriate for Code Review.

Comment: Note that `{k: v for k, v in zip(...)}` can be just `dict(zip(...))` - dict can be constructed from iterable of key-value pairs.

Comment: What exactly is the role of `quarters` since you don't seem to use it to specify a list of valid quarters. `Q4-22` is created in the output even if not present in `quarters`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need `pandas`, and you don't need to parse the date. Since the dates are always in the same format, you can get the quarter from a simple list lookup. Use a `collections.defaultdict` to avoid having to check if the key exists in the dictionary.

Also, you don't need the `quarters` list because you can infer the quarter from the date.

```
import calendar
from collections import defaultdict

month_names = [m.upper() for m in calendar.month_abbr[1:]]

months = ['MAY-21', 'JUN-21', 
'JUL-21','AUG-21', 'SEP-21',
'OCT-21', 'NOV-21', 
'JAN-22', 'FEB-22','MAR-22', 
'APR-22', 'MAY-22', 'JUN-22', 
'JUL-22', 'AUG-22', 'SEP-22',
'OCT-22']

output = defaultdict(list)
for mmyy in months:
    month, year = mmyy.split("-")
    quarter = 1 + month_names.index(month) // 3
    output[f"Q{quarter}-{year}"].append(mmyy)
```

which results in the desired dictionary:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'Q2-21': ['MAY-21', 'JUN-21'],
             'Q3-21': ['JUL-21', 'AUG-21', 'SEP-21'],
             'Q4-21': ['OCT-21', 'NOV-21'],
             'Q1-22': ['JAN-22', 'FEB-22', 'MAR-22'],
             'Q2-22': ['APR-22', 'MAY-22', 'JUN-22'],
             'Q3-22': ['JUL-22', 'AUG-22', 'SEP-22'],
             'Q4-22': ['OCT-22']})
```

If speed is an issue, you can replace the list lookup with a dictionary lookup:

```
month_nums = {m.upper(): i for i, m in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr[1:])}
...
for mmyy in months:
    ...
    quarter = 1 + month_nums[month] // 3
    ...
```

If you're creating a dict anyway, you might as well map the months to the quarter number and use that directly:

```
month_quarters = {m.upper(): 1 + i // 3 for i, m in enumerate(calendar.month_abbr[1:])}
...
for mmyy in months:
    ...
    quarter = month_quarters[month]
    ...
```

If you really want a *dictionary* instead of a `defaultdict`, you can get that with `dict(output)`.

Comment: `month_names = [m.upper() for m in calendar.month_abbr[1:]]` =)

Comment: @NikolajŠ. I avoided any imports, but that is a good way to save on some typing :)

Comment: I think using stdlib modules is fine, you've already used `collections`, after all =)

Comment: Fair point, @NikolajŠ.

Comment: Thanks for this @pho. I like the solution involving directly mapping the months to the quarter and will use that. I hadn't thought to ignore parsing the dates and appreciate the guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) for your datetime operations, here is a pandas approach:

```
def to_quarter(s):
    '''converts dates to quarters with the Qx-YY format'''
    s = pd.to_datetime(s, format='%b-%y')
    return 'Q'+s.dt.quarter.astype(str)+s.dt.strftime('-%y')

s = pd.Series(months)

# groupby quarter, aggregate as list
# reindex with desired list, convert to dict
out = s.groupby(to_quarter(s)).agg(list).reindex(quarters).to_dict()
```

*The `reindex` is optional, it's only if you want to filter out the dates for which the corresponding quarter is not present in `quarters`.*

Or in pure python with the builtin [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html):

```
from datetime import datetime

valid_quarters = set(quarters)

out = {}
for m in months:   
    date = datetime.strptime(m, '%b-%y')
    Q = f'Q{(date.month-1)//3+1}-{str(date.year)[-2:]}'
    if Q in valid_quarters:  # this test is optional
        out.setdefault(Q, []).append(m)
```

*The `if Q in valid_quarters` test is optional, it's only if you want to filter out the dates for which the corresponding quarter is not present in `quarters`.*

Output:

```
{'Q2-21': ['MAY-21', 'JUN-21'],
 'Q3-21': ['JUL-21', 'AUG-21', 'SEP-21'],
 'Q4-21': ['OCT-21', 'NOV-21'],
 'Q1-22': ['JAN-22', 'FEB-22', 'MAR-22'],
 'Q2-22': ['APR-22', 'MAY-22', 'JUN-22'],
 'Q3-22': ['JUL-22', 'AUG-22', 'SEP-22']}
```

Output without `reindex`/`filtering`:

```
{'Q2-21': ['MAY-21', 'JUN-21'],
 'Q3-21': ['JUL-21', 'AUG-21', 'SEP-21'],
 'Q4-21': ['OCT-21', 'NOV-21'],
 'Q1-22': ['JAN-22', 'FEB-22', 'MAR-22'],
 'Q2-22': ['APR-22', 'MAY-22', 'JUN-22'],
 'Q3-22': ['JUL-22', 'AUG-22', 'SEP-22'],
 'Q4-22': ['OCT-22'],                     # this quarter is not filtered out
}
```

Comment: This achieves the desired result and I appreciate you taking the time to provide two alternative solutions. Really helpful, thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @r0bt

Answer (score 1):

Is it necessary to use date-handling classes or can you just create a 12 element lookup table?

```
MONTH_QUARTER_LOOKUP = dict(JAN=1, FEB=1, MAR=1, APR=2, MAY=2, JUN=2, JUL=3, AUG=3, SEP=3, OCT=4, NOV=4, DEC=4)

def quarter_from_month(input_month:str):
    """ convert string <month abbr>-<year> to Q<number>-<year> """
    month_parts = input_month.split('-')
    assert(len(month_parts) >= 2)
    assert(month_parts[0] in MONTH_QUARTER_LOOKUP)
    quarter_no = MONTH_QUARTER_LOOKUP[month_parts[0]]
    return f'Q{quarter_no}-{month_parts[1]}'

quarter_dict = dict()
for month_year in np:
    quarter_key = quarter_from_month(month_year)
    if quarter_key in quarter_dict:
        quarter_dict[quarter_key].append(month_year)
    else:
        quarter_dict[quarter_key] = [month_year]
```